# Javascript error in a comment //@Deprecated in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

On January 24th around 22:00 UTC, Internet Explorer starting having compilation errors on comments in JS, which includes the `@Deprecated` annotation.

This happens in IE11 in compatibility mode for version 7/8/9
This has been working for years in production and suddenly stop working for internal and external users of a site.

I am not able to find any updates of IE that could cause this, rolled out approximately around Jan 24th 2017

Sample code that would stop compiling :

```
...
element: function (el_) { //@deprecated use: $el
    return myObject.$el(el_);
},
...
```

Anybody else experienced this issue?
Possible cause for this sudden breaking change?

Comment: Can't reproduce this on IE11 (Windows 10)